# Google Actions - Invoking Same Intent Twice Freezes

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am developing an action with Dialogflow and actions-on-google library for Node.js. First, I open the action and then I say, for example: "Bring Pizza" which invokes the 'Pizza' intent. If I say again "Bring Pizza" (in a screen device) action freezes. Happens with any intent I have. Text goes up and action just stops. Note: This only happens with real screen devices, not happening on my phone or device simulator.

My welcome intent just asks a question

```
  // Welcome Intent    
   agent.intent('Open', async (conv) => {
     conv.ask("To test, say: Bring Pizza")
   });
```

Pizza Intent invoked when saying "Bring pizza"

```
// Pizza Intent    
   agent.intent('Pizza', async (conv) => {
     conv.ask("Say bring pizza again"); //Just for test purpose
   });
```

Intents in Dialogflow are fulfilled with a webhook intent call to a Firebase function. [Pizza intent in DialogFlow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YpVy.png). [Open Intent in DialogFlow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPAbI.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It sounds simple, but can you update your question to show screen shots of the Dialogflow Intent screens to show how they're setup? Are you seeing this problem in the simulator as well?

Comment: Hi, thank you. I included the screenshots. No, this problem just happens in a screen device. @Prisoner